# Retrieving the name of the current test case running

Tags: python, testing, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I've seen how to retrieve the name of the current test case running for Python Selenium Unittest.

```
unittest.TestCase.id()
```

How to achieve this using Webdriver Py.test framework?  I'm not using unittest framework so my test looks something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.common.exceptions import *
import pytest, re, time, unicodedata

from pageobjects import locators
from os import sys, path
sys.path.append( path.dirname( path.dirname( path.abspath(__file__) ) ) )



def test_PointsBlockingTableNavigationPageLinksBlockingPointsOnly02(driver, url):
```

So basically, I want to retrieve the name `"test_PointsBlockingTableNavigationPageLinksBlockingPointsOnly02"` to either print it to the screen or use in a filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually the same if you are using the `unittest` framework.

Selenium is a browser automation instrument and not a test framework. For instance, here we have a `unittest` test case where selenium is used:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_title(self):
        self.driver.get("https://google.com")
        self.assertEqual(self.driver.title, "Google")
```

---

In case of `pytest`, have you considered using [`pytest-splinter`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-splinter) package? `splinter` is a convenient wrapper around python selenium bindings. The package [can take automatic screenshots on failures](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-splinter#automatic-screenshots-on-test-failure):

> When your functional test fails, it's important to know the reason.
>   This becomes hard when tests are being run on the continuos
>   integration server, where you cannot debug (using --pdb). To simplify
>   things, a special behaviour of the browser fixture is available, which
>   takes a screenshot on test failure and puts it in a folder with the a
>   naming convention compatible to the jenkins plugin. The html content
>   of the browser page is also stored, this can be useful for debugging
>   the html source.

In general, the full test method name in pytest terms is called `nodeid`. There are multiple ways to retrieve it. One of which is to have a custom reporter based on `TerminalReporter` reading the failure headline, see example at [`pytest-wholenodeid`](https://github.com/willkg/pytest-wholenodeid/blob/master/pytest_wholenodeid.py).

Comment: @rwbyrd could you please show an example test you have and elaborate more about why do you need the name of the test? Thanks.

Comment: I just updated the description.  Like I said, I just want to retrieve the name of the test case that's currently running.  I plan to use it in my error code so that when I take screen shots, the screen shots will have their name associated with the test case that fails to prevent a mix up.

Comment: @ alecxe I'm an idiot... lol.  That definitely would help you if I had said I was using Py.test, huh :-).

Comment: @rwbyrd yeah, it's better now. I've updated the answer and added one pytest specific option. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe for the pytest-splinter suggestion.  I will check it out!  In the meantime, is there not a way to retrieve the test case name to print on the screen or use in a file name until I implement the pytest-splinter package?

Comment: @rwbyrd okay, I've updated the answer, I hope it helps.